Method to wait until user is logged in in order to continue
I'm using
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()

on Google Colabs in order to login before the rest of the script runs.
However, the script continues before I've logged in, causing future runs to fail.
I know I can do something silly like input("Press Enter once you have logged in..."), but what I really want is something like:
while True:
    if huggingface_hub.is_logged_in():
        break

so that the code continues automatically once the user is logged in.
Is there any way to do this? If not, what are my best options?
